# Communicate with backend method through Ajax

Tags: java, html, asp.net, ajax, angularjs

I am trying to communicate with a method using Ajax and AngularJS but I'm not getting a response and the alert outputs `undefined`.

*Index.cshtml*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
// Displaying the table is working
    <div>
        <table class="table" ng-controller="UpdateController">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="c in cities">
                <td>{{c.Id}}</td>
                <td>{{c.City1}}</td>
                <td>{{c.Country}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
// Here I add the controller for adding records -->
    <div ng-controller="AddRecord">
        <form id="form1" ng-submit="send()">
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>City: </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtCity" ng-model="addCity" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Country: </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtCountry" ng-model="addCountry" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('UpdateController', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("http://localhost:50366/api/cities")
            .success(function (response) { $scope.cities = response });

        });        

        app.controller('AddRecord', function ($scope, $http) {
// Function responsible for communicating with backend  
            $scope.send = function () {    
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AddCity.asmx.cs/PostCity",
                    data: "{'city':'" + $scope.addCity + "','country':'" + $scope.addCountry + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.d);
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.d);
                    }
                });
//Here is one I tried using text as the datatype:
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AddCity.asmx/PostCity",
                data: "city=" + $scope.addCity + "&country=" + $scope.addCountry,
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                }
            });

            };
        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

*AddCity.asmx* with the method I'm trying to access

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using AngularWebApi.Models;
using AngularWebApi.Controllers;

namespace AngularWebApi.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for AddCity
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class AddCity : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string PostCity(string city, string country)
        {
            City newCity = new City();
            newCity.City1 = city;
            newCity.Country = country;
            //Eventually I want to add the city to the database
            CitiesController controller = new CitiesController();

            controller.PostCity(newCity);

            return "Posted!";
        }
    }
}
```

*Index.cshtml* resides in `Views/Home` and *AddCity.asmx* resides in `Views`. I tried to use `url: "../AddCity.asmx/PostCity"` as well.

**Edit**

I quickly created a new project and set it up, the exact same thing is happening, here are the steps:

- New web api project
- New ADO.net Entity data model and link it to my DB
- New Web API 2 controller with actions using Entity Framework passing the table from DB and entity I got from pevious step.

Then I edit Index.cshtml to show the XML from `API/CITIES` as a table. This time I added my service in the root of the project and just trying to call the auto created `HelloWorld` with the `$.ajax` `POST` function.

I do see a warning in the FF error console. Literal translation from dutch: `Cross-Origin-Request blocked: ....`

Furthermore the `error` is triggered within the ajax call. The WebService is not being reached afaik.

This is the complete reply I get when I click the button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The resource cannot be found.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
            <br><br>

            <b> Requested URL: </b>/Home/MyWebService.asmx/HelloWorld<br><br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[HttpException]: A public action method &#39;MyWebService.asmx&#39; was not found on controller &#39;AngularTutorial.Controllers.HomeController&#39;.
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->
```

**Edit**

The POST method in the controller:

```
// POST: api/Cities
        [ResponseType(typeof(City))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostCity(City city)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Cities.Add(city);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = city.Id }, city);
        }
```

Comment: could be cross-domain problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: @JohnnyAW Running/debugging this locally on localhost.

Comment: I've make a same app, there was some problems due to web browser. Try  with IE... And look in the dev tools the operations

Comment: different port is a different domain as well, empty result on a request smells like browser hides the data due to security violation(e.g. cross-domain)

Comment: Have you allow in you're web.config all the request ?

Comment: @alexis No that did not came with the tutorial :). And when running it with IE i get server error `Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for....`, `Requested URL: /Views/AddCity.asmx`

Comment: do you get the `alert` from success or from error? Are you sure `PostCity` on the server-side is actually executed?

Comment: Try to display the requested url and checks if everything is right

Comment: try to log the entire response object

Comment: @JohnnyAW I am getting the message from Error. I do not know if PostCity is executed.  Debugging is another issue I have. `The breakpoint will not currently hit`. I already unchecked the `enable just my code` in the debug options.

Comment: I also get this error when pressing the button `A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll`

Comment: what is the HTTP-Code on the response? You can check it with developer-tools in your browser

Comment: @JohnnyAW I don't think I get any, you mean the error console in FF do you? It stays empty other then the SignalR longpolling errors.

Comment: I noticed I have a double `web.config`, One in views and one in the root. Could this be the culprit?

Comment: no, i mean the HTTP-Code (like 404). Open developer-tools and switch to network-activities before sending the request. Press the button and you will see your request. It will show some HTTP-Code after the request was answered by the server

Comment: @JohnnyAW I get a document with `<title>The resource cannot be found.</title>` and below the document multiple errors, this is the first `[HttpException]: The file &#39;/Home/Views/AddCity.asmx&#39; does not exist.`

Comment: @JohnnyAW I edited my question could you be so kind to have a look at it?

Comment: if you get cross-domain error after setting up a new application I would guess you use `localhost` with port of the first application in the `ajax`-call. Can you show where and how you define `http://localhost:50366/api/cities` controller?

Comment: @JohnnyAW The XML at that location is created automatically when I add the `ADO.NET entity data model` and assign a Controller for it. I followed a tutorial for this. It then shows how to retrieve the data from the table using that location.

I just want to access the .asmx method so I can perform queries on the database.

Comment: can you post a link to that tutorial?

Comment: @JohnnyAW http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/06/05/a-step-by-step-guide-to-working-with-the-asp-net-web-api-and-angularjs.aspx

Comment: @JohnnyAW It has not anything to do with calling the Method in the `WebService`, thats what I'm figuring out on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm, I think I got it: you try to create a new POST-Method, but according to the tutorial, there is already a POST-Method in the City-Controller:

> By clicking on Add, we are able to create the Cities Web API using the scaffolding. The created controller class will have a Web API for **all the CRUD** operations on the city table.

that means you simply need to send your ajax-call to `http://localhost:50366/api/cities`:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://localhost:50366/api/cities",
       data: "{'country':'" + country + "','name':'" + cityName + "'}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (msg) {
             alert(msg.d);
       },
       error: function (msg) {
             alert(msg.d);
       }
      });
```

Make sure you only have 1 web application running, so you can avoid unnecessary problems.

btw. I'm not sure, if the controller will accept `json` maybe you need to send the data as xml...

EDIT:
I updated the json data. Your city-object has 3 properties: `country`, `id` and `name`. If you send a POST request you are about to create a new object, so you don't need to send the `id`.

For `PUT` and `DELETE` (if you want to implement this functions) you will need to add the `id`to the url:
`http://localhost:50366/api/cities/:id`

EDIT2:
ok, the xml should looks like this:

```
data: "<City><Country>" + country + "</Country><Name>" + cityName + "</Name></City>",
```

don't forget to change:

```
contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "xml",
```

Comment: That makes sense but I'm not quite there yet. The post gets a "purple" 500 Internal Server Error. The answer is `Message:"An error has occurred."`, `ExceptionMessage:"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."`. `ExceptionType:"System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException"`. `StackTrace...` I updated my answer with the Controller method you probably mentioned. I need to supply a city object. This is why I wanted to post to a webservice so I could create the city object there.

Comment: ok, now the error-message shows that you are passing wrong data. Try to send the data as xml

Comment: A city object also has a ID. But this is the `PK` and is auto incremented so I don't want/need to supply it.

Comment: I updated the answer, if it will not work, try to send the data as xml

Comment: Getting very close. I have another error though... `Error in line 1 position 7. Expecting element 'City' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AngularTutorial.Models'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'City', namespace ''. ` Seems that the namespece is wrong, how would I supply that to my data?
`data: "<City>" + $scope.addCity + "</City><Country>" + $scope.addCountry + "</Country>",`

Comment: I added xml-example in the answer. Can you add the full xml, that you get by the 'GET' method so I can copy the namespace?

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot. This is my final data string: `"<City xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AngularTutorial.Models'><City1>" + $scope.addCity + "</City1><Country>" + $scope.addCountry + "</Country></City>"`. However I still get a undefined response back but the record gets inserted. Now I need to update the table without refrefreshing it. I will try to implement @tomastrajan answer to update the table after the post.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ajax, even if it worked you would still have problems because `$.ajax` calls are not in Angular.js context and you would have to manually `$scope.apply()` the returned value. Use angular `$http` service instead. You can find how to use it in [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). It is very flexible, supports all request methods, query params, request body, etc... also supports interceptors to handle all your requests. All `$http` calls return promise by default (also use `.then()` handler instead of success and failure handlers).

Comment: Url should be real url where the service is exposed. I donr know asp.net that good but I suppose if its callable then there must be som real url endpoint where the class and its methods is triggered.

Comment: `$http.post('/my/real/url', dataObjectThatWillBeSentAsRequestBody, params: { optionalQueryParam: 'value'}).then(function success(){}, function error() {});`

Comment: @tomastrajan I think the problem is, he doesn't know what is his real url, or how to bind a function to a specific url...

Comment: Then there might be maybe some router or so but the url is exposed in the end. Simmilar to what he does in his example `$http.get("http://localhost:50366/api/cities")`

Comment: Does not work either: `$http.get('/MyWebService.asmx/HelloWorld').
                    then(function(response)
                    {
                        alert("Success: " + response);
                    }, function(response)
                    {
                        alert("Failed: " + response);
                    });`

Comment: First of in ajax you sended it as `post` so use `$http.post()`, second pass data as secod parameter of post similar to what you did in ajax. Third try in browser different url combinations so that you are sure you are targeting the end point.

Comment: @tomastrajan Yes, tried that. Anyway, I got it to work using the Ajax post. But like you said it will not update my view. Yet if I supply the exact `xml` data string as in the ajax post it post will fail. `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.` Do you have any idea how to supply the data for `$http.post`?

Comment: @tomastrajan Well I got it to respons succesfully using headers but it does not insert a new record. I am building a custom `var req = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:58543/api/cities/PostCity',
                    headers: {
                        contentType: 'application/xml; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'xml',
                    },
                    data: data
                }`